# How to fetch data from external json file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-table

I am working on a React Table. How can I fetch data from an external json file and display the data from that json file?

Here is my CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8zznpzyv

I have added a json file. Being a beginner in React, I am not aware about how to fetch data from an external json file and display the data from that json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your JSON file through a variable (using let, const), and import it into your file where you need that JSON data.

have a look:-

**sample.js**

```
const sampleData = [
   {
     "firstName": "Sam",
     "lastName": "Jones",
     "age": "a"
   },
  {
     "firstName": "Sam1",
     "lastName": "Jones1",
     "age": "a"
   },
]

export default sampleData;
```

and now importing it in my file where i want to use my data

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sampleData from './sample.json'

export default class Home extends Component{
    render(){
         return(
              <div>
                { sampleData.map((item, i) => {
                   return (
                        <div>
                          <h4> My Name is {item.firstName} {item.lastName} and my age is {item.age}.</h4>
                        </div>
                   )
                 }
              </div>
          )
     }
}
```

Comment: Can I assign that constant to a state variable?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean to say

Comment: I meant if I have the json in a different file and I am trying to use its values in a different file then can I assign that constant to a state variable? Can you kindly show me in my CodeSandbox?

Comment: I cannot see any change. Probably you haven't saved after forking. Also I want to remove the data: makeData() method and get data from the json file

Comment: Can you click on fork, then do the change and the save. It will generate a new url.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have upvoted your answer and marked it correct